# Sublime Elm Language Support Package build error in Windows [WinError 2]

Tags: sublimetext3, elm

I installed Sublime Language Support Package following the instructions. I tried both ways of installing the package. I get the syntax highlighting to work.
But when I try to build the project I get this error message:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['elm-make', 'Main.elm', '--output=build\\Main.html', '--report=json', '--yes']]
[dir: C:\Users\webdev\Desktop\elm\scorekeeper\src]
[path: C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\webdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\webdev\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\webdev\AppData\Roaming\npm]
[Finished]
```

Elm is installed globally in the following path: 
C:\Users\webdev\AppData\Roaming\npm
I get this from "where elm-make":
C:\Users\webdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\elm-make
C:\Users\webdev\AppData\Roaming\npm\elm-make.cmd

I also found the issue here and its temporary solution.
https://github.com/elm-community/SublimeElmLanguageSupport/issues/12

The temporary solution is to edit "Elm Make.sublime-build" file from the package and change "elm-make" fields in "variants" to "**elm-make.cmd**". As for elm-format you would need to edit "Elm Language Support.sublime-settings" preferably the user settings. The "elm_format_binary" field should have the following value: "**elm-format.cmd**"

Answer (score 1):

Do you have foo.elm in the same directory as the command you ran?

Comment: The command is build which calls elm-make which is installed globally. I made sure that it is in the path.

Comment: Right, but the file you are trying to compile, foo.elm. Is that file in the same directory as the command you ran?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If I run elm-make in the same directory, it works. But I am using the build command through Sublime. I need it that way so I can see all the errors in Sublime.

Comment: I think you are going to have to figure out how to map Sublime's build command to an elm-make, perhaps you could move your foo.elm file to be in the folder sublime expects it to be in for now?

Comment: I believe the issue is that elm-make is not executable. And elm-make.cmd is executable by Windows. So real solution is a patch to the package. But so far so good with the change in the configuration that I described.